# In yii framework for php how do you know which controller function to call on a particular url hit?

Tags: php, ajax, yii

I work in laravel but in that we define in routes.php which controller action is to call on perticular url for eg.

```
route::get("login", "loginController@getLogin");
```

here we defining to call getLogin Action of controller loginController.php when thi url is hit http://********.com/login

but Now I am working with yii and it seems messy because i had defined a Action in controller posting the data to the action from view but view gives error because it didn't know which controller function . it gives invalidRouteException I found it in error_log.

Comment: Which version of Yii you are using? If Yii2, read [this article](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-routing.html).

Comment: Never mind. I'm sure it's Yii2 because of name of thrown exception.

Comment: logincontroller@actiongetlogin will be called on login/getlogin
with the default yii routes settings.. you can configure it in config/main.php in the url manager.. I recently had to work on a project  in yii too.

Comment: @aslawin I had already seen this page but it has very little description about routes it only explains Url creation. it didn't explain how and where to create them.

Comment: @MubasharAbbas , dude I don't have main.php file in config

Comment: Please post your code of controller actions and view with form.

Answer (score 0):

you can use UrlHelper

```
$url = Url::to(['post/view', 'id' => 100]);
```

In this case is called the controller `post` the action `view` with the `id=100`

see this doc for guide http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-routing.html

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-helper-url.html